# If $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $1$, prove that $\exp(-X)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

Tags: statistics

This is what I have so far:

The PDF of $X$ is  $$f_X(x)=e^{-x}$$ when $x\geq0$ and $0$ otherwise. The CDF of $X$ is $$P(X\leq x)=F_X(x)=1-e^{-x}$$ when $x\geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise. I know that I want to end up with the pdf of $Y=e^{-X}$ being $$f_Y=1$$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise, hence a uniform distribution. So,

\begin{align}F_Y(y)&=P(Y\leq y)\\
&=P(e^{-X}\leq y)\\
&=P(-\ln(y)\leq X)
\end{align}
 I don't know how to proceed from here. Also, I know that $X=-\ln(Y)$, but I am not sure how to use it/ if I need to.

Comment: Since $U=1-e^{-X}\sim U(0,1)$, by symmetry, $1-U\sim U(0,1)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom but then how would you show that $1-e^{-X} \sim U(0,1)$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I know this, but do you think appealing to that fact will be helpful for the OP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You only need to observe that $$\Pr (-\ln y \le X) =1 - \Pr(X < -\ln y) = 1 - \left( 1 - e^{\ln y}\right) = y.$$

Hence, $F_Y(y) = y$, and $f_Y(y) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you! I guess a follow up question would, how do I get the correct domain? Once I get to the point that $F_Y(y)=y$, wouldn't I get that the domain is $y\geq 1$?

Comment: @KaylaB Since $Y = e^{-X}$, you know that $Y \in (0,1)$. This follows from the fact that $X \in (0,\infty)$. (Try looking at the graph of $e^{-x}$ for $x > 0$.)

Comment: Ahh, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}F_Y(y) &= P(Y\leq y) \\&= P(\exp(-X)\leq y) \\&= P(X\geq -\log(y)) \\&= 1 - P(X\leq-\log(y)) \\&= 1 - (1 - \exp(\log(y))) \\&= y\end{align*}$$ and hence $$f_y = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d y} F_Y = 1$$